# Slow MySQL query with multiple joins, max() and group by

Tags: php, mysql, performance

I've got a serious problem. Our Intranet is getting slower and slower. One of the mainreasons seems to be a slow mysql-query (it appears in the slow-query.log).
That query is asked every time an intranet-site is opened.
It looks like this:

```
SELECT w.Datetime, w.User_ID, w.Status, e.Lastname
FROM worktimes AS w
INNER JOIN employees AS e ON w.User_ID=e.ID
RIGHT JOIN (SELECT max(Datetime) AS Datetime, User_ID
            FROM worktimes
            WHERE Datetime>".$today." // variable of today 0.00 o'clock
            AND Location='".$llocation['ID']."' // variable of one of 9 locations
            GROUP BY User_ID) AS v
        ON v.User_ID=w.User_ID AND w.Datetime=v.Datetime
ORDER BY e.Lastname;
```

The worktimes-table is somewhat greater with up to 200k rows (momentary 90k to testing reasons) and 13 columns. The whole query goes through a loop with 3 to 9 cycles.
Has someone an idea how to make the queries faster?

edit: As wished here is the EXPLAIN-result.

```
id  select_type     table       type    possible_keys   key        key_len  ref               rows  Extra
1   PRIMARY         <derived2>  ALL     NULL            NULL       NULL     NULL              44006 Using temporary; Using filesort
1   PRIMARY         w           ALL     NULL            NULL       NULL     NULL              92378 Using where
1   PRIMARY         e           eq_ref  PRIMARY,ID      PRIMARY    4        ais_v1.w.User_ID      1 NULL
2   DERIVED         worktimes   ref     Location        Location   767      const             44006 Using index condition; Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort
```

Comment: Can you do a `EXPLAIN SELECT` of the query ?

Comment: You mean more details? Ok, I will update the question.

Comment: No I mean execute the exact query with `EXPLAIN` in front of it and post the results here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `w` table needs an index on `INDEX(Location, Datetime)`. This should improve the performance.

Comment: You can set an index inside a query? Or shall I change the database table and set an index to the fields location and datetime?

Comment: I changed the database table and set an index to the fields location and datetime. Does the database use it by itself or do I have to involve its name in my query?

Comment: The name of the index is only useful for doing `DROP INDEX`.  You do nothing; the query should automatically use the index.

Comment: Just to clarify, I am not talking about 2 separate indexes: `INDEX(Location), INDEX(Datetime)`; I am recommending a single, composite, `INDEX(Location, Datetime)`.  If you are using some kind of UI, it may not be obvious how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

you dont need to use worktimes twice

you can do it as follows:

```
SELECT max(w.Datetime) AS Datetime, w.User_ID, w.User_ID, w.Status, e.Lastname
        FROM worktimes w left outer join employees e
        on e.User_ID=w.User_ID 
        and w.Datetime>".$today." // variable of today 0.00 o'clock
     AND w.Location='".$llocation['ID']."' // variable of one of 9 locations
        GROUP BY w.User_ID
        ORDER BY e.Lastname;
```

it will run faster than your existing query

Comment: Erm... if you kill the subquery "AS v" than there is no more any possibility to use v.User_ID or v.Datetime ;)

Comment: And if you change the query this way, you dont get the last entry in worktimes, but a random one from the results. Thats the reason I made this complex subquery.

Comment: in this case you can use a temp table in which store the output of this query, and use trigger of manual query to insert data into this temp table as it is inserted into main tables

Comment: The first thought should not be let's add a temp table. That might be the last thought